# Why does Selenium get the child elements slowly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, web-crawler, implicitwait

For example, HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="utf-8">
```

this element don't have child element, when I use code:

```
List<WebElement> childElements = ele.findElements(By.xpath("./*"));
```

the program uses a very long time (about 30s) return a result. And the result size is right which is zero.
So how can I resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation [findElements()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-)  method is affected by the `implicit wait` duration in force at the time of execution. When implicitly waiting, `findElements()` method will return as soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will return an empty list if the timeout is reached.

Possibly you have set [implicitlyWait()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) somewhere before this block of code and configured as **30** seconds. Hence the *TimeOut* occurs at **30 seconds**.